# I need some help with いざゆけ七変化

Tags: grammar, translation, words, verbs

I have almost the complete definition of this sentence

> いざゆけ七変化

I'm using this website "www.jisho.org" to translate words that I still don't know in Japanese.

I'm aware that いざ is an adverb that translates to now, well or come(now) and that 
変化 translates to change when used as a verb but what I can't understand on this sentence is this word ゆけ七 used in the sentence.

Comment: You seemed aware that ゆけ was a verb [in your earlier post](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/39008/i-need-help-with-understanding-this-sentence), but now you've gotten things more confused and come up with ゆけ七 as a single word.

Comment: I want to know what this word ゆけ means not 七, because I know that 七 means seven

Comment: http://jisho.org/search/%E4%B8%83%E5%A4%89%E5%8C%96

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, Babymetal song.

いざゆけ is an old-fashioned way of saying "Go!"

Go, as in  [Go, Speed-racer]  or いざ行けソラン

<sub>いざ行けソラン/吉田亜矢, コロムビアゆりかご会 - 歌詞検索サービス 歌詞 ...
www.kget.jp/lyric/22550/いざ行けソラン_吉田亜矢,+コロムビアゆりかご会
バビューンと ソランが走る バビューンと ソランが駆ける じゃまなビルは とびこえろ 車は軽く 追いこそう バビューンと ソランが走る バビューンと ソランが駆. ..........</sub>

> https://kotobank.jp/word/%E4%B8%83%E5%A4%89%E5%8C%96-520919
>
> 七変化　シチヘンゲ  ------  しち‐へんげ【七変化】
>
> １ 変化舞踊の形式の一。7種の小品舞踊を組み合わせ、一人の俳優が連続して早変わりで踊り分けるもの。七化(ななば)け。→変化物(へんげもの)
>
> ２ ランタナの別名。
>
> ３ アジサイの別名。

A fox was long believed to have magical morphing powers.

A fox may take 7 forms, thus 【七変化】.

[Henge], by iself, means Monster, or Ghost.

> へんげ 【変化】 本来の姿を変えて現れること。その現れたもの。化物。妖怪(ようかい)。

> http://jisho.org/word/%E5%A4%89%E5%8C%96-1
>
> へんげ  変化 ------- Noun, Suru verb -- 1. goblin; ghost; apparition; bugbear

This song lyrics don't seem to mean much.  Just a collage of cute-sounding fragments.

Answer (score 1):

"Yuku" is an archaic form of the verb "iku", to go, and "yuke" is the imperative, equivalent to "ike", meaning "go" as a direction or command.